# {N} 8 Why is the component failing to load?

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to build a rudimentary app to learn the basics and I'm stumbling on the most basic part- navigation. I keep getting the error-

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onClick failed
System.err: Error: Failed to load component from module: ../home/home-view
```

I've organized my code into folders as follows-

```
app/
    app-root.xml
    app.css
    app.js
    views/
        main/
            main-page.xml
            main-page.js
        home/
            home-view.xml
            home-view.js
```

main-page.xml -

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="setupMain" class="page">
    <ActionBar title="My Simple App" icon="" class="action-bar"/>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button text="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-sm " tap="navToHome" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.js -

```
export function setupMain(args) {
  const page = args.object
  alert(args.object);
}

export function navToHome(args){
  const button = args.object
  const page = button.page
  alert('button: ', button, '\npage; ', page)
  page.frame.navigate('../home/home-view')
}
```

home-view.xml-

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingToHome" class="page">
    <ActionBar title="Home" icon="" tap="goToMain" />
    <StackLayout>
        <Button text="Back" backgroundColor="darkgray" tap="navBack" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

home-view.js-

```
export function setupHome(args) {
  const page = args.object
  /* page.bindingContext = createViewModelHome()*/
}


export function navBack(args){
  const button = args.object
  const page = button.page
  alert('button: ', button, '\npage; ', page)
  page.frame.goBack()
}
```

I'm not sure why it's failing to load from the home-view page. Tutorials haven't been much help.

What am I doing wrong here? What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. No need to traverse up the folder path

```
page.frame.navigate('../home/home-view')
```

removed the "../" and changed it to "views/" and it works.

```
page.frame.navigate('views/home/home')
```